# Connecting a USB 3 hard drive to a Mac Mini

Tags: mac, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, usb-3

I've got a [USB 3 external hard drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005HMKKH4) and a [Mac Mini 2012](http://www.apple.com/mac-mini/specs.html) with USB 3 ports. If I want to get USB 3 speeds on the hard drive, I assume I need a special USB 3 cable with the blue inserts. They seem to be pretty hard to find though. For the ones I need, do they need to be A Male to A Male cables? For instance, would [this one from Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003VTZ070) work, and give me USB 3 speeds of up to 3.2 gigabits?

Comment: Any USB 3.0 cable that has the correct connectors will work.  It appears that the HDD requires a Male A connector.  You would need to verify that before you order the cable.

Comment: Okay thanks. There are so many different types of USB 3 cables that it can become confusing after awhile.

Comment: You need at least a single Male A connection ( which goes to the pc itself ) the connection to the hdd you have to determine that.  The box itself shoudl tell you what is included.  You can also contact WD for assistance.